# Why is the following channel operation deadlocking? i.e. downstream <- <- upstream

Tags: go, concurrency

I have two channels, upstream and downstream. My objective is to read data from upstream and pass them to downstream. However, when context is cancelled, I'd like to exit gracefully without deadlock.

I was trying to be "smart" and did something like the following.

```golang
func main() {
    upstream := make(chan struct{})
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func() {
        <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
        cancel()
    }()

    // Buffered downstream ensures no blocking in this scenario
    downstream := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("context is killed")
    case downstream <- <-upstream:
        log.Println("transferred value from upstream to downstream")
    }
}
```

Then I got myself a deadlock. However, if I stop being lazy and do the following,

```golang
func main() {
    upstream := make(chan struct{})
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    go func() {
        <-time.After(5 * time.Second)
        cancel()
    }()

    // Buffered downstream ensures no blocking in this scenario
    downstream := make(chan struct{}, 1)
    select {
    case <-ctx.Done():
        log.Println("context is killed")
    case val := <-upstream:
        downstream <-val
        log.Println("transferred value from upstream to downstream")
    }
}
```

It exited perfectly fine with no deadlock. Can you please enlighten me, what is the key difference between

```golang
downstream <- <-upstream
```

and

```golang
val := <-upstream
downstream <-val
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The select statement isn't operating on the `<-upstream` receive statement, it's operating on the `downstream <-` send statement.

Before the select case can determine if the `downstream <-` send statement is ready, it first has to evaluate the argument expression, which is `<-upstream`. Because nothing is ever sent to `upstream`, that evaluation is blocked. This means you never get to the select cases at all.

The equivalent multi-line code would look like this, which makes it very apparent why it doesn't work.

```
val := <-upstream
select {
case <-ctx.Done():
    log.Println("context is killed")
case downstream <- val:
    log.Println("transferred value from upstream to downstream")
}
```